# How can I open a URL in external browser using Phonegap+cordova in sencha touch app for ios?

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm building a sencha touch app for ios. In order to open URL in external browser , I have included phonegap and cordova. I tried using both this functions to open URL.but didn't work.please help me.

```
 Ext.device.Device.openURL('http://www.bing.com');

 navigator.app.openUrl('http://www.bing.com',{ openExternal:true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple window.open('http://www.google.com') should work and if you want to open the web page in a browser instance within your app, you should consider using [InAppBrowser Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) which uses same window.open and degrade gracefully to default

Comment: I want to open it in external browser.window.open open the URL in app itself..right?

Comment: thanks for the info... Actually it was the issue with version of cordova..I have changed it and now window.open works.

Comment: Can you put more information regarding exact versions and changes you did, to help others.

Comment: I was using `cordova-1.8.0rc1.js` , changed to  `cordova-2.7.0.js` 
and   It worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, *window.open()* didn't work in all cases. Another solution is assign the URL to *window.location*. Example for opening an external Url using a button:

```
Ext.Button.create({
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'open url',       
            handler: function () {  
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
            });
```