# Using Cordova, how can I open external URLs in Chrome, instead of the in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

This question has been asked [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208609/cordova-why-would-inappbrowser-plugin-be-required-to-open-links-in-system-brows/32227524#32227524) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454263/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-external-browser-using-phonegapcordova-in-sencha-touch), but all of the solutions date back to 2013, and I haven't got any of those answers to work with the latest versions of PhoneGap Build / Cordova.

I have a link like this which I want to open in Chrome on Android.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/humphreybc" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
```

In `config.xml` I have the following rules:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I have tried using `window.open(url, _system)` as suggested in other answers – and included the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin –  however:

1. This solution doesn't seem to work, links just open in the in-app browser
2. I'd rather simply use target="_blank" instead of using an onClick handler for each link

I've also followed the instructions [in this blog](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jul/02/External-Links-in-Cordova-for-iOS) and added a handler for links with the `_target='blank'` attribute:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href;
  window.open(url,"_system");                    
});
```

...but still the links open in the in-app browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android

Comment: @PeterScott Thanks for the comment, but I don't believe it's a PhoneGap Build problem. Also, that answer is 2.5 years old so probably not relevant now.

Comment: How did you install the plugin? that code should work. You can try with `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,"_system"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going back through old questions and marking them as answered. I ended up doing this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  return $(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return window.open(this.href, '_system');
  });
};

if (!!window.cordova) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

Comment: Can your solution play m3u8 on chrome if we pass it m3u8 url?

Answer (score 0):

I use Cordova with JQM and I use this function to handle opening a link in the device browser.

```
function open_url( link ) {
   var ref = window.open(encodeURI( link), '_system',        'transitionstyle=fliphorizontal');
}
```

Perhaps worth trying including the encodeURI .. what html framework/libs are you using ( ionic/JQM other? )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (in your JS code):

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to use Chrome or any system-default protocol handler based on user-settings within a Cordova app. On iOS, and possibly other platforms, `_system` does not work as-expected with protocols like `googlechrome:` (nothing happens with inappbrowser version 1.1.1 and cli Cordova 5.4.1 or iOS js cordova.version = 3.9.2). Based on [my quick scan of the source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m#L100) `_self` targets the hybrid app webview, `_system` is passed off and every other target goes to another webview. I found a way to hide the iab window using `hidden=yes` and it just passes off the request to the OS as-is. So this effectively does a system call of the protocol. Apps will need appropriate allow origin/intent statements in config.xml like you mentioned and possibly also checking or adjusting the protocol (eg change `http:` to `googlechrome:`) when opening in this script below.

```
$(document).on('click', (function(base){
/*
this single-page hybrid app uses fragment (ie #/go/here/now ) to navigate
so links will always have the same base url eg 
file:///path/to/app.html
http://localhost/path/to/app.html
*/
var open;
base = base.location.origin + base.location.pathname;
return function(e){
    var a, href;
    if(!(a=e.target.closest('a')) ||  (href=a.href).indexOf(base) === 0 || !href) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    // assuming cordova is available with the plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
    // use with any protocol eg: 'googlechrome://www.google.com/' tel:+18005551212 http://stackoverflow.com
    window._external_app_window = (open || (open = ((window.cordova||{}).InAppBrowser||window).open))(
        href, '_external_app_window', 'hidden=yes'
    );
};
})(this))
.on('resume', function(){
    if(window._external_app_window)    window._external_app_window.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, You can try once:

```
"googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url

i.e. window.open("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url,"_system"); // here you can try with _system or _blank as per your requirement
```

Answer (score -2):

> you can try this one

```
 <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/humphreybc', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Open Browser</a>
```